# Module tagging name length

Tags: discussion, tags

If you all choose to [allow questions about specific modules](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/should-module-specific-questions-be-posted-here), you probably have to agree on a common way to tag them. I see that [taxonomy-access.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy-access.module), [update.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update.module) and others of the format [name#.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name%23.module) exist. That is great, but I think that you (like us at the WordPress Stack Exchange) will soon run into the maximum length of a tag, at 25 characters. [We chose](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-should-we-tag-questions-about-specific-plugins-or-themes) [plugin-#name#](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-%23name%23) as a format, but some plugin names are longer than the 18 remaining characters, and I think that Drupal also has some popular modules whose names are longer than that?

So, if you reach an agreement on whether to allow plugin questions and how to tag them, maybe we can join forces to ask the SE team to increase the length of tag names for both of us?

Answer (score 1):

The ".module" part is not necessary for tags referring to modules.
We use [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) for the Views module, and [cck](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cck) for CCK; in the same way we could use [taxonomy-access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxonomy-access) for Taxonomy Access.

The problem is with [update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update), which could be confused for a tag for questions about updates, and for those modules whose short name is a common word.

Comment: Yes, but maybe you will move to a stricter scheme later in the beta phase? We did this to prevent confusion (with common words) and for consistency (so all plugins start with `[plugin-*]`), but of course you don't have to do this too. It's just that *if* you would choose a similar tagging scheme, then we could bundle our request.

Comment: We could decide for a specific schema; it's just too early for that. I cannot quantify in how many cases such ambiguity would happen, but I will consider the length limit and asking for longer tags.