# Is there a naming scheme for module specific tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Regarding [Module tagging name length](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/module-tagging-name-length), is there a reason we do not have a naming scheme for module specific tags?

Here is a collection of what seem to be module specific tags currently in use using different naming conventions.

[views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) - Module name only.

[entity-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-module) Module name with 'dash' module.

[migrate.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate.module) Module name with 'dot' module.

Would it make sense to setup a naming scheme specific to 'specific modules'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have renamed [migrate.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate.module) as [migrate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate), and merged [migrate-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-module) with it. The reason I kept [migrate.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate.module) (after renaming it) is that it had already a tag wiki.

The reason there was [entity-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-module) (which I renamed [entity-api-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-api-module)) is because the entity API is a part of Drupal, and there is a third-party module that is the Entity API module. There was the need to have a tag for that third-party module, and for questions about the Drupal entity API; that is why there is [entity-api-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-api-module), and [entity-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-api). Notice that Drupal 8 has the Entity module; questions for this module should be tagged [entity-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-api).

If Views becomes part of Drupal 8, we will have a similar problem. Probably we should have [views-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-module) for the third-party module, and [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) for the Drupal core part. That is in the case the Views module becomes part of Drupal 8, and it doesn't change name during that operation. Code of the CCK module was incorporated in Drupal 7, but as part of modules such as the Field module, the Field UI module, the Text module, and the Number module.

Generally speaking, there is no need to include .module, or -module in a tag. It is done when it is not differently possible to disambiguate two tags that would differently be the same.

Comment: So to help solidify our naming scheme for Drupal specific tags, should we entertain the idea of using `-module` to differentiate contributed modules from core modules with identical names as in the case of the entity api?  If so, including heavily documented Drupal terms (possible list of a few http://drupal.org/glossary ) that collide with contributed and core module names might make sense as well.  Would something like this be too isolated to add to the FAQ for reference purposes?

Comment: There is no need to differentiate between Drupal core modules, and third-party modules. The Entity API module is the only unfortunate case, where the module should have probably be named differently.

Answer (score 3):

Totally agree with the disparity between dots and dashes...I've changed all questions tagged with [migrate.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate.module) to [migrate-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-module), which follows the standard tag naming 'strategy' more accurately.

With regard to the `-module` bit...I don't think there's an issue there to be honest.

[entity-module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-module) is so-named because there's another tag ([entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity)), which is a synonym of [entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entities). Since entities are a specific concept in Drupal core, it makes sense that there be a separate tag for those questions, and the ones specifically about the entity API module.

Following the same logic: since there's no such concept as 'views' in the core of Drupal, the [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) tag doesn't actually need to have `-module` at the end, as it's already implied.

Comment: There is no need to retag all the questions using a tag, when the purpose is replacing a tag with another one: Moderators can rename tags. Thank you for taking care of this, anyway.

Comment: Doh, didn't realise that. Ah well, I know for next time!