# Add "general reference" as reason to close a question

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

In *English Language and Usage* is possible to close a question because it is a "general reference."
That closing reason would apply for *Drupal Answers* too.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: @Robert Harvey Would not that closing reason apply also to _Drupal Answers_? If what being asked is the first result of a search, could not the answer be closed as "general reference"?

Comment: Yes, it is the same idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "general reference" close reason is being rolled out on a very limited basis and only on a few sites which have shown it to be a problem. You would have to make a strong case that wide-spread, unwelcomed questions are being asked that can easily be found on sites like dictionary.com, imdb.com, or the opening paragraph of Wikipedia.

In the meantime, if you hare seeing questions which are not being asked in good faith, closing as [not a real] question should serve your needs.