# Is drush covered under Drupal Answers

Tags: discussion

Is drush covered under the remit of Drupal Answers?

For:

1. It's a drupal extension
2. Interacts with core and contrib modules
3. PHP with hook like system similar to Drupal

Against:

1. It's a cli tool
2. Not exactly module related

With projects such as drush deploy announced at DrupalCon it might be possible that an increase in questions on drush might occur.

What do people think?

Answer (score 4):

It's a Drupal tool, so I would say that questions about Drush are on topic on Drupal Answers.
I doubt somebody would use Drush without using Drupal.

Clearly, simple questions for which one could find the answer in the documentation are less welcome. If we had the "[general reference](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/add-general-reference-as-reason-to-close-a-question)" closing vote, we could close those questions with that reason.